# Why is not saga data serialized to database

Tags: serialization, rebus, saga

When trying to save my Sagadata class, the properties are saved, but not serialized.

Like this:

```
   public class MySagaData: ISagaData
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public int Revision { get; set; }

        public string MyString{ get; set; }
        public int MyInt{ get; set; }
    }
```

I populate the Data object in saga with data.

Here is the data saved to the database:

```
{
  "$type": "MySagaData, MySagaDataProject",
  "Id": "b1e04d95-5b0b-4fca-aa63-aa1b44afacce",
  "Revision": 0,
  "MyString": null,
  "MyInt": 0
}
```

The Id is correctly saved.

If I change the data, by updating the database, the properties are mapped correctly into the data object.

Any ideas what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the Automapper wrong:

```
base.Data =  Mapper.Map<Messagedata, MySagaData>(message);
```

By using it this way, it is a success:

```
Mapper.Map<Messagedata, MySagaData>(message, base.Data);
```

Comment: Good you figured it out :)